# Relay Command CanExecute is only invoked in the viewmodels constuctor once but won't invoke again when Properties are changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand, relaycommand

*What I want to do*:
When my view is loaded, one can see several textboxes that are compulsory fields(marked red). For as long as those textboxes are not filled out, the button "NEXT" is disabled, otherwise enabled:
[image]

The XAML for the button:

```
  <Grid Grid.Row="10" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="11" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <Button ToolTip="Die Pflichtfelder bitte ausfüllen!" Content="WEITER ZU GRUNDLAGEN" Command="{Binding AngebotKopieren}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Button>
            </Grid>
```

*What I tried*:
On the internet I read about the RelayCommand and hence decided to add it to my project to achieve the above mentioned goal.
In the Viewmodel's constructor I included it like this:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    AngebotKopieren = new RelayCommand(CopyTemplate, CanCopyTemplate);
}

private ICommand _angebotKopieren;
        public ICommand AngebotKopieren
        {
            get { return _angebotKopieren; }
            set { _angebotKopieren = value; OnPropertyChanged("AngebotKopieren"); }
        }
```

As you can see, I used two methods called **CopyTemplate()** and **CanCopyTemplate()** . For now, it does not matter what the first one does but the latter is supposed to return true when all compulsory fields are filled out and false if not. For this example I only used one compulsory field for reasons of simplicity:

```
private bool CanCopyTemplate(object obj)
{
    if(//(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Nachname) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Vorname) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Angebotstitel) && 
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelAnrede) //&& String.IsNullOrEmpty(StrasseWohnort) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(PLZ_Wohnort) 
        //&& String.IsNullOrEmpty(Wohnort)))
        )
    {
        return false;
    }
              
        return true;
            
}
```

However, when I fill out SelAnrede (string that is bound to the Combobox Selected Item property with Update Source Trigger=On Property Changed, the button remains disabled.
What am I missing? Why is the CanExecuteChanged()-Method not invoked when I change the SelItem property in the view? Why is the CanCopyTemplate()-method not invoked again?

Here is the RelayCommand-Class for a better overview:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Konstruktoren

        /// <summary>
        /// Erzeugt ein neues Command, das immer ausführen kann.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">Die Ausführungslogik...</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Erzeugt ein neues Command
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">Die Ausführungslogik...</param>
        /// <param name="canExecute">Die Logik zum Ausführungsstatus...</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        #endregion // Konstruktoren

        #region ICommand Members

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameters)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameters);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                //throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            remove
            {
                //throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameters)
        {
            _execute(parameters);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members
    }
```

Comment: Where are you raising the `CanExecuteChanged` event?

Comment: nowhere because in the RelayCommand guide on the internet it said that it triggers automatically and thus was not necessary to raise it manually. Is that wrong? How would you manually raise it?

Comment: It doesn't "triggers automatically". Most implementation have a method that raises it. See my answer.

Comment: You must remove the explicit ICommand.CanExecuteChanged implementation or implement it properly. Currently, the control will try to subscribe to the CommandManager (via the CanExecuteCanged event) but the handler is never registered (since add() is empty).

Comment: I personally implement a method on my RelayCommand called `Refresh()` then in my ViewModel I call said method for property that is relaying on that property. Bear in mind that RequerySuggested has a performance issue if you have many on properties.

Comment: By the way Prism has a `DelegateCommand` that binds to `PropertyChanged` for those properties that are relevant for the command en/disable toggle.
You just have to pass the property names. Then the command acts like a switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a property whose value is checked in the `CanCopyTemplate` method of the command is set, you should call a method of the command that raises its `CanExecuteChanged` event.

So, for example, the setter of your `SelAnrede` property should be implemented something like this:

```
private string _selAnrede;
public string SelAnrede
{
    get { return _selAnrede; }
    set
    {
        _selAnrede = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelAnrede));
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
}
```

The `CanExecuteChanged` event is not something that is raised "automatically" but most implementations of `ICommand` out there have a method that raises it for you. You only need to make sure that you actually call it.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking  about that, too but when I have let's say 25 properties I would have to add the line ÀngebotKopieren.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();`for all those properties. Is there maybe a solution that fires an event when changes happen that I can add to the viewmodels constructor and it takes care for all of those properties changes at once?

Comment: Hook up an event handler to the `PropertyChanged` event and call the method from this event handler?

Comment: Your solution does not work for me as CanExecuteChanged() is an event handler, not a method. Also, SelAnrede is not an object but a string. AngebotKopieren.CanExecuteChanged(); is giving me an error.

Comment: So change the type of `SelAnrede`? It was an *example*. How am I supposed to know what type a "SelAnrede" is? It's not important. As for the method, you obviously need to define one if you use your own command implementation. It doesn't define itself...

Comment: By the way, given your current implementation, you should be able to call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` to refresh the status of the command.

Comment: Remove the explicit and wrong `event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` implementation first.

Comment: That solved it, thank you! After removing the event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged() it worked.

Comment: @timunix Don't explicitly call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` in every property set(). This is not necessary and will only degrade the application's performance. `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested ` is usually invoked by the framework when the user interacts with controls.